# PHP-cURL --> follow a ruby redirection

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, redmine

I am using trying to extract the wiki documentation from a page on my website (redmine). I successfully retrieved the redirect to the login page, send post username and password field, but then I arrive on a page with a ruby redirect from redmine and I can't go further. The ruby code in the file "response.rb" of redmine is:

```
def redirect(url, status)
  self.status = status
  self.location = url.gsub(/[\r\n]/, '')
  self.body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{CGI.escapeHTML(url)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
end
```

I don't kbow enough about ruby to modify redmine's code, so is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: If you are being redirected, then I would **hope** that the redirect URL is in the headers.  Please post the headers from your cURL request.

Comment: I thought so to, but there were no headers, it was the most basic page possible with nothing in the head, no doctype, etc.
Anyway I found the solution yesterday and posted it, I just forgot there was the captcha verification so my solution wasn't posted.

Comment: He means the http headers, not the head of the html page. An http response should have headers.

Comment: Ok, well I dont't know how to retrieve the headers in php, but anyway I found a solution with the cookies, as posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternate solution!

IF anybody else has that problem with redmine or any other redirect:

1. Use cURL to login first
2. Save your session to a cookie
3. Use cURL to get your secured page that needs authentification.

   ```
   <?php
       $tempFilename = tempnam("/tmp", "COOKIE");

       // Login
       $curlHandle = curl_init("http://bob.com/login");

       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tempFilename);
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

       $dataArray = array(
            "username" => "bob",
            "password" => "password"
       );

       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataArray);

       $output = curl_exec($curlHandle);

       // Getting the wiki
       $curlHandle = curl_init("http://bob.com/wiki");

       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tempFilename);
       curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

       $output = curl_exec($curlHandle);
       echo $output;
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Would tell cURL to follow any properly configured redirects (anything that sends the Location: header).